# Does Chebyshev's theorem provide a lower bound of the primorial $n\#$ such that $n\# \ge 2^{n/2}$

Tags: prime-numbers, primorial, chebyshev-function

I found the following claim [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-best-known-lower-bound-for-product-of-primes-which-are-less-than-n-in-terms-of-n/5c69b87caa1f099b554f90e2/citation/download):

> Chebyshev's theorem gives the lower bound $2^{(n/2)}$.

Is this correct?

If $n\#$ is the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) of $n$, does it follow that:

$$n\# \ge 2^{(n/2)}$$

As I understand it, from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1890792/48606), Chebyshev's thereom establishes that:
$$\pi(2n) \ge \frac{n\log 2}{\log(2n)} $$

Are these two estimates related as the poster claims?  I have worked on it but am not able to derive the given lower bound of the primorial from the Chebyshev estimate.

Can someone help me to understand if the poster is correct?